# Removing the List of Corrections from the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, fixme

I'm using the package `fixme` and the command `\listoffixmes` which generates a list of fixme notes on a page titled *List of Corrections*. However, the title appears in the table of contents and messes with the other section titles throughout the front matter. I'm using `amsbook` as my document class.

Is there a way to remove the List of Corrections from the Table of Contents?

Comment: Do you use a `KOMA`-Class with the option `listof=totoc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using `KOMA`. In this case you can redefine the heading. It is important that you create a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\lox@heading{\section*{\@fxlistfixmename}%
\@mkboth{\@fxlistfixmename}{\@fxlistfixmename}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffixmes
\clearpage
\section{foo}
Text\fxnote{hallo}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

`fixme` uses an old definition of the heading. According to the package `scrhack` you can redefine the `listoffixmes` so that `toxbasic` is used. So you can use `setuptoc{}{}` to influence every `\listof...`. Here an example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\makeatletter
\addtotoclist[float]{lox}
\setuptoc{lox}{chapteratlist}
\renewcommand*{\listoffixmes}{\listoftoc[{\@fxlistfixmename}]{lox}}
\makeatother

\setuptoc{lot}{totoc}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listoffixmes
\clearpage
\section{foo}
Text\fxnote{hallo}
\end{document}
```

For more details see the documentation of `KOMA`.

**EDIT 2**

Explanation documentation amsbook:

> In amsart.sty \@startsection, \@sect, and a couple of other things are
>   redefined to fix a few hard-coded things that would interfere with the
>   desired style. The most noteworthy difference is that all section
>   headings will go into the table of contents (governed by secnumdepth
>   as usual), EVEN WHEN THE * FORM IS USED. The only section heading not
>   listed in the table of contents is the heading for the toc itself.

```
\documentclass[]{amsbook}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}\endgraf}
\listoffixmes
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}\endgraf}
\clearpage
\chapter{bar}
\section{foo}
Text\fxnote{hallo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Marco, I'm using `amsbook` not `KOMA`. Can you port your code to that document class? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my post.